# Why $\lambda\equiv\nu(\mathbb{R})$ for compound poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I've seen this notation $\lambda\equiv\nu(\mathbb{R})$ in the book of Tankov and Cont for compound poisson process. I thought before that $\lambda$ (jump intensity) can be choosen independently of jump measure $\nu$. What does this notation imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jump intensity can be chosen independently of jump measure

This looks like an abuse of terminology in this context. You should clearly distinguish between the *jump measure* and the *normalized jump measure*.

If the total jump intensity is finite, it is sometimes convenient to think of a normalized (probability) measure $\nu / \nu(\mathbb{R})$, which represents the conditional distribution of an individual jump. In this case this is true, we can choose $\lambda := \nu(\mathbb{R})$ and the normalized measure $\nu / \nu(\mathbb{R})$ independently. However, in other situations it is more natural not to normalize $\nu$ - and it is indeed impossible if $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$. So, shortly speaking, this is just the *definition* of $\lambda$.